# Error shown even if directory already exists

Tags: php, if-statement, directory, mkdir

I am making a intranet customer manager in PHP. For each customer a directory is created for the shop to add files into. What my script is supposed do is if no directory exists create it, if it does exists dont create it.
What is actually happening is if the directory already exists I am getting the following error :

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in     C:\server2go\server2go\htdocs\customermgr\administrator\components\com_chronoforms\form_actions\custo    m_code\custom_code.php(18) : eval()'d code on line 14
```

So what is happening it is trying to create it anyway, even though the if statement should stop it ?, im confused on what I am doing wrong :-S .

```
    <?php
    $customerID = $_GET['cfid'];
    $directory = "/customer-files/$customerID";

    if(file_exists($directory) && is_dir($directory)) { 
    }
    else {


    $thisdir = getcwd(); 


    mkdir($thisdir ."/customer-files/$customerID" , 0777); }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

`if(file_exists($directory) && is_dir($directory)) {`

with:

```
$thisdir = getcwd();
if(file_exists($thisdir.$directory) && is_dir($thisdir.$directory)) {
```

or better:

```
   <?php
    $customerID = $_GET['cfid'];
    $directory = "./customer-files/$customerID";

    if(file_exists($directory) && is_dir($directory)) { 
    }
    else {


    mkdir($directory , 0777); }

    ?>
```

Comment: and move `$thisdir = getcwd();` before the comparison.

Comment: Hi, I still get the error about the directory already existing

Comment: What if you try `$directory = "./customer-files/$customerID";` and `mkdir($directory , 0777);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just took a short look but i would try this:

```
$directory = $thisdir . "/customer-files/$customerID";
```

and remove $thisdir from mkdir();

also you should move your $thisdir before the $directory declaration

Answer (score 1):

The function [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) does not use relative paths, where [is_dir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) can. So instead, use the common denominator and pass an absolute path to these functions. Additionally you can move the call to `getcwd()` into the `$directory` assignment and reuse `$directory` later for creating the directory.

```
<?php

   $customerID = $_GET['cfid'];

   // Get full path to directory
   $directory = getcwd() . "/customer-files/$customerID";

    if(file_exists($directory) && is_dir($directory)) { 
       // Do nothing
    }
    else { 
       // Directory doesn't exist, make it
       mkdir($directory , 0777); }
    }

?>
```